# How to open the properties dialog for a Font without a PropertyGrid at runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, propertygrid, uitypeeditor

Consider a form with a `TextBox` and a `Button`.  When you click that button you should get the `Font` properties dialog at run-time.

During designer you can click the button off to the right of the property in the `PropertyGrid` and get the editor window to manipulate the Font for this `TextBox`. During run-time, if you add a `PropertyGrid` to the form and point it to the `TextBox` you can also get the editor window.

How can I get this editor window at run-time through say, a button click without having a `PropertyGrid` on the form?

Though I've gotten the `PropertyDescriptor` and the `UITypeEditor` from this descriptor, I don't know what to call to get the instances of `ITypeDescriptorContext` and `IServiceProvider` when calling `UITypeEditor.EditValue`.

EDIT - Since I asked this problem of a control that has an easy solution, I've asked another question related to this topic: [How to open the properties dialog for a Complex Property without a PropertyGrid at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13627120/how-to-open-the-properties-dialog-for-a-complex-property-without-a-propertygrid)

Comment: Thanks for the edits Picrofo EGY, i'll keep the formatting in mind in the future.  This certainly makes it easier to notice objects in the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FontDialog` to show the standard font dialog box:

```
new FontDialog().ShowDialog();
```

To read/write fonts:

```
var dlg = new FontDialog();
dlg.Font = textBox1.Font;
if (dlg.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    textBox1.Font = dlg.Font;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps I should submit another question... this was really not the approach I was looking for... I was trying to simplify the question because I'm trying to do this for a custom UITypeEditor control that doesn't have such a function yet (trying to create it)